Lavann model estimation failed
So I started using lavaan and sem() today. Worked fine with a couple of constructs/latent variables and a single regression model. However, lavaan now fails. Even when I tried to remove the new variables out of the regression model, I still get this error:
'''
    Warning message:
    lavaan->lav_lavaan_step11_estoptim():  
    Model estimation FAILED! Returning starting values

'''
What could be causing this?
Dput result:
dput(head(data2))
structure(list(everlied = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Buswebsite = c(3, 
1, 4, 1, 3, 3), BusFacebookpage = c(3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3), 
periodicals = c(3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3), internetsearch = c(3, 4, 4, 2, 
4, 4), googlebuslisting = c(3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3), 
internetdiscussforum = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4), consumerratingssite = 
c(3,4, 5, 2, 4, 4), friends = c(5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5), family = c(5, 
5, 5, NA, 4, 5), doctors = c(4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4), politicians = 
c(3,1, 1, 3, 1, 1), salespeople = c(3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1), like = 
c(3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1), newimmigrants = c(3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1),
businessowners = c(3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1), celebrities = c(3, 3, 1, 2, 
3, 1), commercialactors = c(3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1), religious = c(4,
4, 4, 2, 4, 1), socmediainfluencers = c(3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1), 
teachers = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1), gender = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), age 
= c(5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2), education = c(4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3), income = 
c(3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4), region = c(3, 3, 7, 7, 3, 7)), row.names = 
c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

My model is pretty tame. The observed outcome variable is ordinal (it's Likert scale values). The predictor variables for demographic are categorical. The rest of the variables are also ordinal. The first time I tried, I just used the first two latent vars. Coincidentally, I couldn't find anything about this error per se but found one post that mentioned about variance. I did try inserting auto.var = TRUE but that didn't help.
Here's what I have.
`
    model <- '
    + person  =~ family + friends
    + demographic =~ age + gender + income + education + 
    region 
    + instit =~ doctors+politicians+religious+businessowners
    + soc =~ salespeople + celebrities + commercialactors + 
    socmediainfluencers + newimmigrants
    + info =~ Buswebsite + BusFacebookpage + periodicals + 
    internetsearch + googlebuslisting + internetdiscussforum + 
    consumerratingssite
    + like ~ person + demographic + instit + soc + info 
+ '
> model_out <- sem(model, data=dat2)

Thank you

Taking a wild guess because we cannot see any of your data or model structure, I would say probably because you are trying to fit a too-complex model with too many parameters to a too-small dataset. Andrew Gelman calls this the folk theorem of statistical computing: "When you have computational problems, often there's a problem with your model." https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2008/05/13/the_folk_theore/

It would be great in the future, even if you don't provide the full dataset in your post, to provide enough information for us to get an idea of what you are doing. For example, the code of the model specification and at least a description of the data. Better yet provide the first few rows of the data in a form we can easily get into our R session. You could run dput(head(data)) and copy the output into your question.

I will revise my post to include this. So sorry! It's nothing crazy. Be right back!

Hi qdread, I've added dput in my post

Hey my original comment was assuming your dataframe is called data. But we would need the dput output from the dat2 dataframe that has the data you're fitting the model to. dput(head(dat2))

Ah! I'll fix that. That's a duh-doy on my part.

Yes, now seeing the model and data I would still say that the model might be too complex for your dataset. How many rows are in your data?

qdread: 351 rows. But it ran fine with 2 latent variables.

Try adding one latent variable at a time and see how many it takes for the estimation to fail.

So, after trying several times, I decided to consolidate some of the latent variables. It seems that lavaan/sem doesn't like more than 4 constructs. Worked perfectly with 4 latent vars.
